# Retrieve ClassWork from GoogleClassroomApi [403] Python

Tags: python, google-classroom

I am trying to retreive the classwork of each course from Google Classroom API.I have succeeded in getting all the courses, but I am stuck on the course work: *<HttpError 403 when requesting https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/courses/167997334462/courseWork?alt=json returned "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.">*.

This is the code I am using:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.students.readonly']


def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Classroom API.
    Prints the names of the first 10 courses the user has access to.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                r"\test\credentials.json", SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('classroom', 'v1', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Classroom API
    course_work_results = service.courses().courseWork().list(courseId="167997334462").execute()
    
    [...]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I have generated the credidentials using admin account; I've also tried several different Scopes, but same error.

Could you guys please help me here?

I am using Python 3.9.

Thanks,
Alexandru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Since you are using the scope

  `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.students.readonly`,

  I assume you are a student.
- Students are only allowed to access course work of the courses where they are accepted course participants.
- Trying to retrieve the course work of another course will result in an 403 error.
- If you are not a student, but an Admin of your Google Workspace domain, you should use a wider scope, e.g.
  `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.me.readonly`.
- Please mind that after changing the scopes in your source code you need to delete your token file to trigger new authentication flow.